# I had to graph income and expenses, wanting only the current year to graph. React sequelize

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js

I had to graph my income and expenses, wanting only the current year to be graphed. And not specifying only the year shown by allowing the graph to scroll indefinitely.

### Api

```
router.get("/revenuelimit", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await revenue.findAll({ limit: 5 , order: Sequelize.literal("id DESC") });
  res.json(result);
  console.log(result)
});
// January
router.get("/January", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await revenue.findAll({
    where: { 
      createdAt: { 
        [Op.between]: [ "2019-12-31 19:30:00.000 +00:00", "2020-01-30 19:30:00.000 +00:00"]},}});
        res.json(result);
  // res.json(result);
  console.log("January");
});

// February
router.get("/February", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await revenue.findAll({
    where: { 
      createdAt: { 
        [Op.between]: [ "2019-01-31 19:30:00.000 +00:00", "2020-02-28 19:30:00.000 +00:00"]}}});
        res.json(result);
  // console.log(result);
});
```

### GetAxios

```
 componentDidMount = async() => {
    // Revenues
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/revenue")
        .then((e) => this.setState({GetRevenue: e.data}));
        console.log(this.state)

      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/revenuelimit/")
        .then((e) => this.setState({GetRevenuing: e.data}));
        
    // month
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/January")
        .then((e) => this.setState({January: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/February")
        .then((e) => this.setState({February: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/March")
        .then((e) => this.setState({March: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/April")
        .then((e) => this.setState({April: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/May")
        .then((e) => this.setState({May: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/June")
        .then((e) => this.setState({June: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/July")
        .then((e) => this.setState({July: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/August")
        .then((e) => this.setState({August: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/September")
        .then((e) => this.setState({September: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/October")
        .then((e) => this.setState({October: e.data }));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/November")
        .then((e) => this.setState({November: e.data}));
      await httpClient
        .get ("http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/December")
        .then((e) => this.setState({December: e.data}));
  }
```

I retrieve the information by The first day of the month to the end of each month of each month

### Chart Bar

```
const data = {
      labels: [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'รายรับ',
          fill: true,
          lineTension: 0.5,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
          borderCapStyle: 'butt',
          borderDash: [],
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
          pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
          pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
          pointBorderWidth: 1,
          pointHoverRadius: 5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
          pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 10,
          data: [ Januarys ,
                  Februarys,
                  Marchs,
                  Aprils,
                  Mays,
                  Junes,
                  Julys,
                  Augusts,
                  Septembers,
                  Octobers,
                  Novembers,
                  Decembers
                ]
        },
```

January information is 2019 and October is for 2020. I only want the current year to be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your API call for february, you are getting all data points from 31. January 2019 to 28 February 2020. You have to change the range here to 31. January 2020 (or 1. February 2020).
Also: 2020 is a leap year, so the last day of February is the 29th,

```
// February
router.get("/February", async (req, res) => {
...
        [Op.between]: [ "2020-01-31 19:30:00.000 +00:00", "2020-02-29 19:30:00.000 +00:00"]}}});
...
});
```